# How to show an array items into list with on/off button in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array with key and values which I want to show in a list with on/off switch.

```
{
  "cCode1": "Unique code",
  "cCode2": "Brand Code",
  "cCode3": "Pattern Code",
  "cCode4": "Assortment Code",
  "cCode5": "Size Code",
  "cCode6": "COLOR Code",
  "cName1": "UniqueCode Name",
  "cName2": "Brand NAme",
  "cName3": "Pattern Name",
  "cName4": "Assortment Name",
  "cName5": "Size Name",
  "cName6": "COLOR Name",
}
```

This is something I want to achieve, also how to handle switch state.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
yourArray.map(item => {

return <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height:  50}}>
        <Text style={{someStyle}}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Switch/>
   </View>
})
```

This is a pseudo Add the result of above array on ScrollView so that UI will be visible in all devices.

Comment: this list is dynamic, i guess this method is for static array only. And there are around 50-60 keys, i just sent around 10 keys just for an idea

Comment: your list will be your array here. Doesn't matter the length of list same logic will work any length of array. 

My one more suggestion here. If your list if big then instead of scrollView use FlatList. This will save memory and improve performance.

Comment: I am using flatlist only but the type of array cannot be loaded in flatlist data directly